# Plotting normal curve with extremely small variance

Tags: plot, curve-fitting

I need a graph of a normal bell curve centered around t with a variance as small as possible (without being straight line). I've found a bunch of methods to plot a normal graph, but none where the variance/standard deviation can be explicitly stated. Here's what I am looking for but preferably even thinner:

[image: normal]

UPDATE:
[image: error]

Comment: How about `xscale`?

Comment: I'm extremely new to latex so you are going to need to be more specific, sorry I should have clarified

Comment: You can make an MWE, or find what you want Seeing examples on the web page [TexExample.NET](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/area/statistics/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{declare function={myGauss(\x,\y,\z)=exp(-(\x-\y)*(\x-\y)/(\z*\z));}}
% this is a Gaussian centered at \y with a width controlled by \z
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw plot[domain=-0.1:0.1,variable=\x,samples=100] ({\x},{myGauss(\x,0,0.03)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: Here is a proposal. I can't really recommend to just refer to the Gaussian a "the plot below".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\tikzset{declare function={myGauss(\x,\y,\z)=3*exp(-(\x-\y)*(\x-\y)/(\z*\z));}}
% this is a Gaussian centered at \y with a width controlled by \z
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{wrapfigure}[15]{r}[10pt]{5.4cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex] (-1,0) -- (2,0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw[-latex] (-1,0) -- (-1,3.5) node[left]{$y$};
\draw[thick] plot[domain=-0.5:0.5,variable=\x,samples=100] ({\x},{myGauss(\x,0,0.1)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A narrow Gaussian.}
\label{fig:Gaussian}
\end{wrapfigure}
In Figure~\ref{fig:Gaussian}, we show a narrow Gaussian.
\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is showing up extremely small in my document, any way to make it bigger?

Comment: @undergrad Bigger meaning higher? If so, do `\tikzset{declare function={myGauss(\x,\y,\z)=5*exp(-(\x-\y)*(\x-\y)/(\z*\z));}}` or something like that. If you mean wider, do `\draw plot[domain=-0.5:0.5,variable=\x,samples=100] ({\x},{myGauss(\x,0,0.15)});` or something along those lines.

Comment: I've attached a screen shot of my issue in my OP

Comment: @undergrad I still don't know whether you want it to become taller, wider, or both. I'd also recommend to put it in a figure environment, possibly a wrapfig since it will be narrow.

Comment: I just want to scale it, so the actual image is larger

Comment: @undergrad I made an update, in which I also show how I would refer to the figure.